# Call to undefined function making site unavailable

Tags: backups

After making a Backup/Migrate copy of source site files, the very source site for unknown reason broke down with this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function link_field_property_info_callback() in /sites/all/modules/entity/modules/field.info.inc on line 30

Most probably it comes from references to the Link module.
I have googled around, but the solutions good for others are not for me, as I cannot access admin to un-install the module. Is there anything I could do here without Drush?

I really do not quite understand the origin of that situation, but I would more like to focus on resolving the effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to (re)move the faulty module's directory, at least temporarily. It should prevent the call and let you access the necessary admin pages.

Comment: Thanks,- I got this after trying to uninstall drupal Commerce - I simply renamed entity/module to entity/module0 then accessed the admin pages to complete the uninstall. seems to be fully working after renaming back the directory

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
    drush sqlq "DELETE FROM cache_field"
```

In case, you are using memcached use the below

```
    echo 'flush_all' | nc localhost 11211
```

drush command worked for me.